# How to stylize a table on C to make titles appear once at the top of the table

Tags: c

I have a table that shows 5 types of information. I want to label every value so it is in line with the information.

This is how a table works and looks:

```
for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    printf("\n %-15s\t%-10s\t%-5s\t%-5s\t%-s\n", ptr[i]->name, ptr[i]->foto,
           ptr[i]->species, ptr[i]->age, ptr[i]->guide);
```

[What it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiB1T.png)

I tried to give a sign to every variable in **printf**

```
printf("\n Nickname: %-15s\tPhoto: %-10s\tSpecies: %-5s\tAge: %-5s\tGuide: %-s\n",
       ptr[i]->name, ptr[i]->foto, ptr[i]->species, ptr[i]->age, ptr[i]->guide);
```

But the problem is, it's repeating the labels every time there's a new object in the table.

[Instead of showing up one time, the labels appear on every line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDU7r.png)

I want to make signs show only one time and at the top of the table, like in the example below.

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuWeU.png)

Comment: It will be hard to give MCVE cause' code is working with a 4 different files to show this table. But I can give you an GitHub project if it would help https://github.com/BohdanNemezis/Course-work.git

Comment: It does take a bit of skill to create an MCVE, but not all that much — witness the code in my answer.  That's close to minimal.  You need to learn to abstract the problem and create code that handles just that problem.  I could modify my code to use an array of a structure type instead of arcane calculations for the numeric values — it would probably be closer to what you've got.  But the formatting techniques do not depend on your specific data.  Taking a step back from your actual code and producing a minimal example is a good exercise in programming skills (very useful in bug reporting).

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right tool? `popen("pdflatex", "w")` would probably be easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is doing what you tell it to do. What you want cannot be produced by the code you are using.

You need one `printf()` statement before the loop that prints the column headings. You then have a second `printf()` statement in the loop that prints the values but not the labels (such as `Nickname:`).

Getting the widths and layout right is tricky. I find it best to have two analogous format strings — one that prints column names (strings) with each column width specified in the format, and one that prints the values using numeric and string formats as needed, with the widths specified.

For example:

- heading format: `"%-15s  %-10s  %5s\n"`
- data format: `"%-15s  %10.6f  %5d\n"`

In practice:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("%-15s  %10s  %5s\n", "Name", "Number", "Count");

    double number = 355.0 / 113.0;
    int count = 2405;
    static const char names[][16] =
    {
        "Ozymandias", "Alexander", "Genghis Khan",
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%-15s  %10.6f  %5d\n", names[i], number, count);
        number *= 2.19;
        count = (count * 4) / 23;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
Name                 Number  Count
Ozymandias         3.141593   2405
Alexander          6.880088    418
Genghis Khan      15.067394     72
```

Note that newlines generally belong at the end of an output format, not at the beginning.